# Rails nested with_option :if used in validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, nested

```
validate :updatable?  # First validation there is
with_options :if => Proc.new { |object| object.errors.empty? } do |updatable|
    updatable.with_options :if => "self.current_step == basic" do |step|
        validates .... bla-bla bla
```

So, before any validations are made, the *updatable* subroutine is called and it populates the `errors[:base]` array with appropriate errors, meaning that object is not updatable. And I wanted it to skip the rest of the validations if any errors are found in this subroutine, but abovementioned example is **NOT** working - it performs all the validations.

But, if I change `:if => "self.current_step == basic"` to `:if => "self.errors.empty? && self.current_step == basic"` is works like a charm.

What I'm doing wrong ? Examples show, that nested `with_option` should work.

Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me, that it's a bug, cause conditions aren't being merged together, so only last of them is actually involved. Hope that someone will pay attention to this one and it will get fixed in future versions.

Comment: It's 2021 and still works like that for Rails 6.0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are right that when nesting two :if conditions, the inner one will replace the outer one and always be checked. A workaround to handle two levels of nesting is:

```
with_options :unless => !(outer condition) do
  with_options :if => (inner condition) do
```

The if and unless conditions do not overwrite each other. I'm not sure I would call this a bug, but it would be nice if you could nest multiple :if conditions.

Comment: I didn't know this. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like it's more to a design consideration to override the if statement. It is more neat to put multiple condition in the last if statement.

Comment: This feels wrong. But there really is no other way huh?

Comment: @Yewness I don't think I agree with this at all.  Scopes don't work this way, which should be almost entirely analogous to nested validators.