# Problems with conditional validation in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord

I have to conditionally validate my `User`. After user registers, he can complete the rest of his profile. It's split into parts, so, for example, there is "Educational background" and "Professional background". Those parts consist of fields, which I have to validate (e.g. presence).

So, of course, these fields shouldn't be validated during registration, but only when the user tries to edit those fields. A natural idea would be to send a `context` parameter in the form, and do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :context

  with_options if: -> { |u| u.context == "educational" } do |s|
    s.validates :university_name, presence: true
    # ...
  end
end
```

But what if I also need to have conditional validation inside the block:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :context

  with_options if: -> { |u| u.context == "educational" } do |s|
    s.validates :university_name, presence: true, if: :finished_university?
    # ...
  end
end
```

Which means that those to `:if`s will clash. I *could* transform every `:if` in the block into an `:unless`, but this will hurt readability, and I really don't want that.

Is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: same question, but no satisfactory answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174435/rails-nested-with-option-if-used-in-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need so many 'if' statements probably your model is flawed. Maybe you need to extract a new model from your User, define new resource and controller.

EDIT:
This gem can be helpful:
https://github.com/stevehodgkiss/validation-scopes

Comment: I agree, that model has too many fields. But I need to work around it somehow, because I came to it when it was already like this, and splitting it would require too much time.

Comment: Maybe this gem can be useful: 
https://github.com/stevehodgkiss/validation-scopes

Comment: Yes! That's it! Update your answer, so I can approve it :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

`validates :university_name, presence: true, if: :finished_university? && lambda {|u| u.context == "educational"}`

Comment: You mean `if: -> { |u| u.finished_university? && u.context == "educational" }`? Yeah, I really want to avoid putting this `u.context == "educational"` in every field, because there are really many of these fields, so it would really hurt readability.